# How can I have separate colormaps for two subplots in Scilab?

Tags: plot, 3d, surface, scilab, colormap

I have two subplots made by surf, since both plotted variables have very different behaviours and scales, I would like to plot them with independent colormaps. I tried coding it as below but the last colormap is the one that gets applied to everything. How can I make it so that each subplot gets a different colormap? The image I'm currently getting with this code is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtFI4.jpg).

```
---- START OF CODE BLOCK ----

f0=scf(0);
subplot(1,3,1);
surf(plotPlan(:,:),N(:,:));
f0.color_map = jetcolormap(32);
xtitle("NUTRIENT SPATIAL DYNAMICS","NBY","NBX","Z");
set(gca(),"auto_clear","off");

subplot(1,3,2);
surf(plotPlan(:,:),A(:,:));
f0.color_map = oceancolormap(32);
xtitle("ALGAE SPATIAL DYNAMICS","NBY","NBX","Z");
set(gca(),"auto_clear","off");
...

---- END OF CODE BLOCK ----
```

Comment: did you try `gca()` or `gce()`?

Comment: I tried both, but none worked. The first didn't work because it handles the axes instead of the surface... The second, 'gce', gives me an error saying that 'color_map' is a property that "does not exist for this handle". This is how I tried to code it. `fig=scf(1);` `subplot(1,3,1);` `surf(plotPlan(:,:), N(:,:));` `e=gce();` `figA=e.children(1);` `figA.color_map=jetcolormap(32);`
Is there any other way to do this? It seems like there should be a simple way to do this that I just haven't found yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color_map property is attached to the figure so it is not possible to set a colormap to each axes.
It is however possible to do what you want following the example below

```
function c=colorindex(z,ncolor)
  //compute the color index for each surface value
  mn=min(z);mx=max(z)
  c=round((z-mn)/(mx-mn)*(ncolor-1))+1
endfunction

//first surface
t=linspace(0,2*%pi,30);
z1=sin(t)'*cos(t);

//second one
z2=z1.*z1;

f=scf(0);clf;
defined a colormap with the catenation of the 2 requested colormaps
f.color_map=[jetcolormap(32);oceancolormap(32)];
//draw the first surface with the first part of the colormap
subplot(211);surf(z1,colorindex(z1,32),"ColorDataMapping","direct")
//draw the second surface with the second part of the colormap
subplot(212);surf(z2,colorindex(z2,32)+32,"ColorDataMapping","direct")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate. Indeed, the example works on my data, but it makes it very complicated to do anything else on the graph window (e.g.: set separate  default scale ranges for both datasets). I've decided to plot each in a separate window so that I can also change their options and explore the outputs some more. But again, thanks for the help!